# Checking values for a dict of objects in python

Tags: python, dictionary, distinct-values

I have a list of dicts e.g. `[{'X':0,'Y':0},{'X':1,'Y':2}]` and I want to check to see if every X and Y value is equal to 0. I have tried some methods such as the all() function and the .values() function but I have been unsuccessful but maybe I have been using them wrong.

I tried
`all(value=={'X':0,'Y':0} for value in mydict)`
but to no success. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: how about `mydict['X'] == 0 and mydict['Y'] == 0`...

Comment: That's not a dict of objects, that's a list of dicts.

Comment: `all(value=={'X':0,'Y':0} for value in mydict)` - This looks correct to me.  How specifically did this fail?

Comment: @0x5453 it give an error with {AtttributeError}'dict' object has no attribute '__dict__'

Comment: @JackTimber That line of code cannot raise that error.  The code you are running is different from the code that you are showing us.  I suggest you edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I think what is missing is the .values() operator?

```
ListOfDicts= [{'X':0,'Y':0},{'X':1,'Y':2}] 


for  dictionaryIndex in range(len(ListOfDicts)):
    result = all(value==0 for value in ListOfDicts[dictionaryIndex].values())

    if result == True:
        print ('The values in the dictionary at index : ' + str(dictionaryIndex) + ' ARE equal to zero.')
    else :
        print ('The values in the dictionary at index : ' + str(dictionaryIndex) + ' are NOT equal to zero.')
```